# Patterns and practices for passing data between templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

As of Meteor 1.1*, what are the **best patterns** and **practices** for passing *data* between templates using *raw* Meteor?

*A [link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/patterns-and-practices-on-passing-data-between-templates/2951) to the Meteor forum asking the same question.*

Answer (score 0):

Some different possibilities:

With block:

```
{{#with post}}
    {{> postTemplate}}
{{/with}}
```

Passing arguments:

```
{{> postTemplate post=post anotherArg=5 moreData="xyz"}}
```

If you also want to use iron-router (and basically all projects should), you can use "data" to return the data context for the page you're loading.

Also, note that child templates inherent parent data contexts. (They don't inherent helpers though).

Comment: Thanks. This is valid, and well flushed out inter-template communication.  What I was actually thinking of was two independent templates, not one template embedded within another.   For example a Posts, and Posts Detail screen.